# Is enzyme 42 dropped by the sea emperor leviathan juveniles?

Tags: subnautica

Am I right, that the sea emperor leviathan juveniles drop the enzyme 42 occasionally? I chased one of the juveniles for 4 in-game days and it didn't drop a single item. How often do they drop the enzyme? Does it fall down to the ground immediately or is it floating in the water?

Answer (score 13):

After they hatched, you find a ball of enzyme 42 right inside the sea emperor aquarium inside the primary containment facility. I also found some balls right outside the portal near the alien tower, where the sea emperor babies left the containment facility.

I'm not sure if they drop more enzyme 42 after/besides that...

Comment: I have seen them drop them after you head toward the juveniles through the portal.

Answer (score 4):

1. They usually drop them inside the Primary Containment Facility aquarium or right outside the Quarantine Reinforcement Platform
2. They float

Comment: +1'd for the float comment, but edit your answer to say neutral bouancy.

Answer (score -1):

you have to make the hatching compound to hatch the eggs of the sea emperor then the baby's will make it!